# How do I know that a complex conjugate is in a unit circle?

Tags: complex-numbers

> How do I know that a complex conjugate is in a unit circle?

For instance, are $0.9 + 0.9i$ and $0.9 - 0.9i$ in a unit circle?

Comment: Do you know the definition of being in the unit circle?

Comment: Hint: the inside of the unit circle is $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| \lt 1\}$.

Comment: "in" a unit circle not same as "on" a unit circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complex number $z\in \mathbb C$ is in the unit circle if $|z|\leq 1$ (strictly inside if $|z|<1$). We calculate the absolute value of a complex number $z = a+bi$ by
$$|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}. $$

Now check if $z = a+bi$ satisfies $|z|\leq 1$ when $a = 0.9$ and $b = 0.9$.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate it norm and it must be less or equal to $1$. In this case,

$$\vert \vert 0.9\pm 0.9i \vert \vert = \sqrt{0.9^2 +(\pm 0.9)^2}= 0.9\sqrt{2}$$

And if you make the algebra, you notice that:

$$(0.9\sqrt{2})^2> 1^2$$

Because 
$$1.62 > 1$$

Comment: "inside" means norm not more than 1,  or strictly less than 1 if "strictly inside".

Comment: Sorry. Correcting right now.